# Comments in mobile version of Ask Ubuntu

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

I am using my mobile to connect to Ask Ubuntu. But the problem is I can't remove/edit comments from mobile version of Ask Ubuntu. Is it problem of my mobile or a known issue in Ask Ubuntu?

Browser: Opera Mini 6.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites [haven't always had perfect support for Opera Mini](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48525/why-do-you-block-opera-mini).

Comment: But all stack exchange site s are super fast from opera mini !

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this bug. Very annoying, I always forget that I can't send anything from my mobile, and whatever I type is in vain...